# Terraform GCP executes resources in wrong order

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have this main.tf file:

```
provider "google" {
  project = var.projNumber
  region = var.regName
  zone = var.zoneName
}

resource "google_storage_bucket" "bucket_for_python_application" {
  name = "python_bucket_exam"
  location = var.regName
  force_destroy = true
}

resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "file-hello-py" {
  name = "src/hello.py"
  source = "app-files/src/hello.py"
  bucket = "python_bucket_exam"
}

resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "file-main-py" {
  name = "main.py"
  source = "app-files/main.py"
  bucket = "python_bucket_exam"
}
```

When executed first time It worked fine, but after `terraform destroy` and again `terraform plan` -> `terraform apply` I've noticed that terraform tries to create object before actually creating a bucket:

[image]

Ofc it cant't create object inside something that does'nt exist. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a dependency between your objects and your bucket (see code below). Otherwise, Terraform won't know that it has to create bucket first, and then objects. This is related to how Terraform stores the resources [in a directed graph](https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/graph.html).

```
resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "file-hello-py" {
  name   = "src/hello.py"
  source = "app-files/src/hello.py"
  bucket = google_storage_bucket.bucket_for_python_application.name
}

resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "file-main-py" {
  name   = "main.py"
  source = "app-files/main.py"
  bucket = google_storage_bucket.bucket_for_python_application.name
}
```

By doing this, you declare an implicit order : bucket, then objects. This is equivalent to using `depends_on` in your `google_storage_bucket_object`s, but in that particular case I recommend using a reference to your bucket in your objects, rather than using an explicit `depends_on`.